# Can you find n without multiplying both sides by 1/(n(n+1)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you find n without multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$?

$\frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+2)}{4}=\frac{8n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Can you find $n$ by expanding first?

Please show working
Thanks

Comment: What is $n$?  Could it be zero?  One cannot divide by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{n(n+1)(n^2+n+2)}{4}=\frac{8n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\iff 3n(n+1)(n^2+n+2)=16n(n+1)(2n+1)\underbrace{\iff}_{\text{when }n\neq0,-1} 3(n^2+n+2)=16(2n+1)\iff$
$3n^2+3n+6=32n+16\iff 3n^2-29n-10=0$. using the quadratic formula we get $n=\frac{-1}{3}$ and $n=10$.

We now have to check $n=-1$ and $n=0$ by hand, they work since they are both zero.

hence the solutions are $n=0,-1,\frac{-1}{3},10$

Comment: I think you mean $n=-1$ rather than $n=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That would just turn a simple problem into a much more unwieldy one.

If you're worried about division by zero, just consider two cases:

Case 1: $n(n+1) \neq 0$:

Do the multiplication by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ to yield $3(n^2 + n + 2) = 16(2n+1)$ and solve that quadratic. Verify that neither of those solutions gives $n(n+1) = 0$ (they don't).

Case 2: $n(n+1) = 0$

In this case, you cannot multiply by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. But you don't need to. Just solve this second, already factored quadratic, to give $n=0$ or $n = -1$.

The solutions to the two cases will give you the full solution set.

EDIT: edited my solution because it seems you edited the original equation!